# Login of many users using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-multiple-users

How can I create a multisession with shared preferences so that two users can login and logout in the same session?

I have the following code.

```
public class Session 
{
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context ctx;
    String [][] usuarios;
    int i,j;

    public Session(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("init", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
    }

    public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedin)
    {
        editor.putBoolean("loggedinmode",loggedin);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean loggedin()
    {
        return prefs.getBoolean("loggedinmode",false);
    }
}
```

I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: Two users maximum? Or any number? Also, SharedPreferences isn't a good way to store lists, a better solution would be to use JSON or just a plain text file.

Answer (score 0):

> You can store lists, you just have to use a clever way. There is this library called Gson it can be serialize and deserialize java objects. So what you can do is create a list of objects call Gson.toJson which converts the object into json string representation of that object, then take it and store as String in shared preference with your unique name.Then to modify read from it, use fromJson , do your thing and save. Hint, this operation can be taxing though it works, consider in the long run to use databases, realm is great.

Comment: Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects.

Answer (score 0):

Why just dont you use SQLite? Sharedpreferences is also can but sharedpreferences intended to save simple values.

If you are using SharedPreferences, just differentiate the key name ex: "User1_session_login", "User2_session_login"

```
public void setLoggedIn(String key,boolean loggedin){
            editor.putBoolean(key,loggedin);
            editor.commit();
}
```